# "C programming language" - Counting characters anomaly?

Tags: c, output, character, counting

In *The C Programming Language book by Ritchie & Kernighan*, in ***§1.5.2 Counting Characters***, two versions of the program are given:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* count characters in input; 1st version */
int main() {
    long nc;
    nc = 0;

    while (getchar() != EOF)
    {
        ++nc;
    }

    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* count characters in input; 2nd version */
int main() {
    double nc;

    for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc) {
        ; // null statement
    }

    printf("%.0f\n", nc); 
}
```

They both compile and work but always output one more character than the actual count of the words.

Example:

```
"milestone" (9 characters) outputs 10  
"hello, world" (12 characters) outputs 13
```

Why is this?
Is it counting the `'\0'` character or the `'\n'` given by me hitting the Return on the keyboard?

FYI: I am running all this on Terminal on *MacOS 10.13.5* and the text has been inputted in *Atom*.

Comment: One way to see what is happening, print out the value of the character each loop, which should provide fairly solid evidence for accepting the second hypothesis. (There is no '\0' character read from the keyboard--)

Comment: @user2864740: you can often type control-@ to enter a null byte from the keyboard. Just an FYI — it is unlikely that it is being typed in this context.

Comment: One easy way to find out, loop only while `getchar() != '\n'` instead of EOF and see if it will output the expected result. Also, why use `double` if you're counting integers? I doubt you will encounter with half a character.

Comment: @Havenard I am following the book by Ritchie & Kernighan. He says that on certain machines Int was 16bit only so Double would give us more "power".

Comment: @NeeratheWildMage Well that's like, when coding microcontrollers or something, and even there you should find types that support 32-bit like `long`. As far as I know `long` will always be at least 32-bit even when coding 8-bit microcontrollers. It's important though to remember that this "power" comes at the expense of more memory, and [when you have 25 bytes of RAM available](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/PIC12C508A) you can't afford to allocate bits you won't need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It counts "one more" because `\n` is counted as well.

For example:

```
echo -n "asdf" | ./a.out
```

Outputs:

```
4
```

But with a newline:

```
echo "asdf" | ./a.out
```

it outputs

```
5
```

Comment: Your code in the Terminal outputs this `-bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory`

Comment: I assumed you compiled one version of your provided code without arguments.
So the binary `a.out` would be compiled and linked.

Also, my version of `echo` has the `-n` switch, to disable echoing a trailing newline.

Comment: I copied your exact same code `echo -n "asdf" | ./a.out`and that is what the Terminal tells me ...

Comment: @NeeratheWildMage Replace `a.out` with the name of the compiled program

Answer (score 1):

It counts your "enter" input too: your word +1 enter input = x+1 counts.

If you type the first value as "EOF value" which is cntrl+z for Windows, the loop won't count "enter" because it will reach "EOF value" before your "enter" input and the output will be zero.